# Sudoers rule not woking as expected

Tags: linux, sudo

I want to allow user `visit` to run comands as user `admin`, but only commands located in a specific directory.
So I added the following rule to the sudoers file:

`visit localhost=(admin) NOPASSWD: /home/admin/`

Inside the directory **/home/admin/** there are two files: `cmd.sh` and `dummy.txt`
The content of `cmd.sh` is:

> whoami
>   touch dummy.txt

Then I login as user `visit` and type:

`sudo -u admin /home/admin/cmd.sh`

and the output for that is:

> admin
>   touch: cannot touch `dummy.txt': Permission denied

But if I login as `admin` and type `./cmd.sh`, the output is:

> admin

and `dummy.txt` is succesfully touched

Why the user `visit` cant touch an `admin`'s file when using sudo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the contents of cmd.sh:

```
whoami
touch dummy.txt
```

Add:

```
pwd
```

I suspect that when user "visit" runs the script with sudo it's not running in the directory you think it is.  You would solve this by passing a full path to the tuuch command, e.g.,

```
touch /home/admin/dummy.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't fully-qualifying the path to dummy.txt on your touch command.  My guess is that you're running the script from a location where 'admin' has no write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -u admin /home/admin/cmd.sh
```

You're telling sudo to run cmd.sh as the admin user in your current directory, which from your description is likely visit's home directory.  admin doesn't have write access to visit's home directory, so it fails.